# Starting server listening for requests from Docker container on mapped port error Socket access permission denied

Tags: docker, sockets, http, server, port

I have a Docker container with an application that sends http POSTs to a configurable endpoint. I am trying to create a http listener on the host machine that listens for these POST messages, by adding a port mapping (eg 8085:8085) and starting a listener on port 8085 on the host.

I am getting the error

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

I have confirmed it isn't an issue with my implentation. I have tried with multiple libraries in both Python and c# and get the same result. When i stop the docker container, the listener binds to the port.

I assume this is a fairly standard issue.
Is there a 'best-practice' way to achieve what i want to do, or any workarounds?

Comment: I'm having the same issue suddenly today with port mapping 49153 to 49153. I'm curious to know if you have Windows as host OS and if it got upgraded in the past 48 hours?